# Can I publish x64 .msix bundle in x86 OS?

Tags: c#, uwp, msix

I made a Universal Windows Platform application. I want to publish this app. My operating system Is x86 and I want to publish to x64. Is this possible?

Comment: Please check the following [resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/package/packaging-uwp-apps)

Comment: Why would you publish something you haven't tested?

Answer (score 2):

Generally, this is not possible, 32-bit OS is not compatible with 64-bit assemblies.  There used be some ways to do this before by modifying some configuration. But I don't recommend this.

My suggestion is that you might need to create a VM with 64-bit OS on your device and then do the work in the VM. Of course, it's better to get a real device with 64-bit OS. After all, it's always the best practice to test your app completely before you publish.